# Windows Server 2008 insists on logging inactive RDP users out

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

We're using Windows Server 2008 as one of our build servers. We login as a special build user via RDP with /console (or /admin) and launch the build agent. After some time Windows decides to log that user out.

We've had similar issues with our dev machines which also run windows server 2008. A dev will go home, login to the console via rdp do some work, then close the session. When he gets back to the office he will be logged out and all his applications closed.

How can I prevent these logouts?

These machines are part of a domain run by a Windows Server 2003 AD Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Tech net](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx) on these settings.  You can manage this using AD or Local Security Policy.

Comment: I'd seen these, but this particular article applies to R2. Things aren't the same in non-R2. I did find the analogous 2003 policy (Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates> Windows Components>Terminal Services>Sessions) and apparently in one of my policies I had the timeout set to 30m. I changed that and hopefully it will fix it. Thanks!